# Is it possible to mock a type with an attribute using Rhino.Mocks

Tags: .net, rhino-mocks

I have this type:

```
[RequiresAuthentication]
public class MobileRunReportHandler : IMobileRunReportHandler
{
  public void Post(MobileRunReport report)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

I am mocking it like so:

```
var handler = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IMobileRunReportHandler>();
handler.Stub(x => x.Post(mobileRunReport));
```

The problem is that the produced mock is not attributed with the `RequiresAuthentication` attribute. How do I fix it?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I want the mocked type to be attributed with the `RequiresAuthentication` attribute, because the code that I am testing makes use of this attribute. I would like to know how can I change my mocking code to instruct the mocking framework to attribute the produced mock accordingly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mocking attributes - C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319002/mocking-attributes-c)

Comment: I will gladly agree with you if you show me where exactly does that post contain the answer to my question. Thanks.

Comment: In what context do you need the class to be attributed with `RequiresAuthentication`? Could you elaborate that a little more?

Comment: How does the code you are testing use the attribute? Could you add a code snippet? The approach to add the attribute to the stub might depend on this.

Comment: This happens inside the OpenRasta framework. It uses the regular reflection API -  Attribute.GetCustomAttributes.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an `Attribute` to a type at runtime and then getting it using reflection isn't possible (see for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397519/programmatically-add-an-attribute-to-a-method-or-parameter) post). The easiest way to add the `RequiresAuthentication` attribute to the stub is to create this stub yourself:

```
// Define this class in your test library.
[RequiresAuthentication]
public class MobileRunReportHandlerStub : IMobileRunReportHandler
{
    // Note that the method is virtual. Otherwise it cannot be mocked.
    public virtual void Post(MobileRunReport report)
    {
        ...
    }
}

...

var handler = MockRepository.GenerateStub<MobileRunReportHandlerStub>();
handler.Stub(x => x.Post(mobileRunReport));
```

Or you could generate a stub for the `MobileRunReportHandler` type. But you'd have to make its `Post` method `virtual`:

```
[RequiresAuthentication]
public class MobileRunReportHandler : IMobileRunReportHandler
{
    public virtual void Post(MobileRunReport report)
    {
        ...
    }
}

...

var handler = MockRepository.GenerateStub<MobileRunReportHandler>();
handler.Stub(x => x.Post(mobileRunReport));
```

Comment: I am sorry. I just do not get it. The stub generated by Rhino.Mocks is of dynamic type, i.e. the type is created at runtime using the `Reflection.Emit` facility, which allows to have a dynamic type attributed as we please. It is all a question of whether Rhino.Mocks knows to exploit this ability of `Reflection.Emit` or not.